# MONGO 3.6 fitler subdocument based on field

Tags: mongodb

Hi i need the query to perform a filter of the hourly nested object.This can be in the aggregation framework. Since the "hour" field is equal to a certain number. I only want to return that number object inside hourly. I tried everything, does anyone know a query for this?

```
{
    "_id" : "08062017/cpu",
    "hour": 1
    "hourly" : {
            "0" : "0",
            "1" : "1",
            "2" : "2"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "08062017/cpu2",
    "hour": 2
    "hourly" : {
            "0" : "0",
            "1" : "1",
            "2" : "2"
    }
}
```

RESULT:

```
{
    "_id" : "08062017/cpu",
    "hour": 1
    "hourly" : {
            "1" : "1"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "08062017/cpu2",
    "hour": 2
    "hourly" : {
            "2" : "2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you gave your hourly objects real property names or flattened them out the following code will work.

Run a project in the aggregate function:

```
$project: {
    hourly: {
             "$let": {
                        "vars": {
                            "field": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [{
                                    "$filter": {
                                        input: "$hourly",
                                        as: "h",
                                        cond: { $eq: ['$$h', '$hour'] } //hour is your property on the base document, h is your variable for the hourly array
                                    }
                                }, 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "in": "$$field"
                    },
                },
}
```

Your current issue is that `hourly` array is a set of objects without consistent fields to map by ex: `"0":"0"` this should be a flat array like so:

```
hourly: ["0", "1", "2"]
```

or a proper object like so:

```
hourly: [{"Zero": "0"}, {"One": "1"}]
```